# incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) F,T exist so that java.util.Collection<T> conforms to java.util.Set<java.lang.Long

Tags: java, collections, transform

I am trying to convert the list of `ComplexItem` to a list of their corresponding IDs `Long`. But getting the above error which doesn't go even after typecasting the `getCollection()` call with `(Collection<ComplexItem>)`

```
Set<Long> ids = Collections2.transform(
                    getComplexItems(), new Function<ComplexItem, Long>() {
                        @Override public Long apply(final ComplexItem item) {
                            return item.id;
                        }
                    }));

 public List<ComplexItem> getComplexItems() {
        ..............
 }
```

Comment: Why not simply do `getComplexItems().stream().map(item -> item.id).collect(Collectors::toSet)`?

Comment: @QBrute that should work but wanted to know what is wrong in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to expect that the [result of `Collections2.transform`, which is a `Collection`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), will be magically transformed to a `Set`. This is the reason for the type matching error in the title.  You'll need either to convert the result to a set explicitly or make do with the `Collection`.

Since you're already using `Guava`, you should strongly consider `ImmutableSet`, so it's

```
ImmutableSet<Long> ids 
    = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Collections2.transform(getComplexItems(), item -> item.id)));
```

Taking a step back, remember Guava was created before Java `Stream`s. It's generally preferable to use language built-ins rather than a third party library, even when it's as good as Guava. In other words, prefer

```
getComplextItems().stream().map(item -> item.id).collect(toImmutableSet());
```

where `toImmutableSet()` is a collector defined by `ImmutableSet`.

Answer (score 0):

you got in the wrong import for Function

try this

```
    Collection<Long> ids = Collections2.transform(
        getComplexItems(), new com.google.common.base.Function<ComplexItem, Long>() {
            @Override public Long apply(final ComplexItem item) {
                return item.id;
            }
        });
```